# GitLab CE - How to disable CI/CD Pipelines on all Projects by default?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I want to disable CI/CD in GitLab CE.

I know this can be done on a per Project basis, but I would like to set it to be off by default, such that when new projects are created, CI/CD is not automatically enabled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that you need to be an admin,

- go to the admin area
- in the left panel go to settings
- choose CI/CD
- then you wanna expand "Continuous Integration and Deployment".
- finally uncheck the "Default to Auto DevOps pipeline for all projects" checkbox.

PS: Don't forget to save the modifications